# Как конвертировать цифровой сертификат с расширением .crt в сертификат с расширением .cer?

Tags: java, openssl, x509certificate, криптография

Я пытаюсь сгенерировать цифровой сертификат и использую следующие команды openSSL.

1)generating a Cryptographic Key Pair and CSR

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout demo.key -out demo.csr

получаю приватный ключ и csr файл

2. generating a self-signed certificate in .crt format:

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in demo.csr -signkey demo.key -sha256 -out demo.crt

Но от меня требуется cer файл, если я правильно понимаю это просто другой формат сертификата. Как правильно сконвертировать сrt файл в cer при помощи openSSL или каким-то другим способом?

Можно ли изначально в этой команде прописать расширение .cer?

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in demo.csr -signkey demo.key -sha256 -out demo.cer

или так делать нельзя?

Comment: если вам нужно другое имя файла, так переименуйте, или сразу указывайте нужное. а вот если нужно другое **содержимое** файла, то вы уточните, какое именно содержимое от вас требуют

Comment: Александр, спасибо, я уточню этот вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Существует два формата PEM: текстовый (можете открыть свой файл crt и посмотреть) и двоичный.

Можете конвертировать свой сертификат так:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in demo.crt -out demo.cer
```

Или сразу экспортировать его в нужном формате:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in demo.csr -signkey demo.key -sha256 -outform der -out demo.cer
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!